# Window, Document vs. $wnd, $doc

Tags: java, javascript, dom, gwt

I know that the following is some kind of the same in GWT:

```
Window and $wnd
Document and $doc
```

Are there any differences, beside that the first is used in Java and the second in JSNI (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Window` is a class plenty of static methods, which you can use for getting or setting certain properties of the browser window, but actually it is not the native browser window object. These method implementations are eventually `JSNI` blocks which use the `$wnd` variable to set/get those properties. Like `Window.alert()` whose implementation would be `$wnd.alert()`. Note that `Window.java` doesn't have access for everything in the browser's window object like `window.console` etc.

GWT uses `$wnd` instead of `window` because compiled code is executed normally in an iframe, and in this context, `window` will reference the iframe window while `$wnd` will reference the parent window. The same occurs with `$doc` which is a reference in the iframe to the parent document.

In the other side `Document` is a java class which extends `JavaScriptObject`, it means that it is an [Overlay](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes) type which basically means that it is a special wrapper for a native javascript object, it does not modify the underlying JavaScript but adds a set of java methods to interact with it. It can be safely cast when passing to jsni.

In summary, although `Document` and `$doc` are not the same in java world, when it is compiled they will be the same, otherwise `Window` it's not an overlay of `$wnd`, it is just a way to access certain methods of the browser window.

Although GWT compiled code delegates to native js objects and methods, don't try to find similarities between js and java objects. GWT has designed an API to develop ajax applications using a set of java objects, widgets, patterns, etc. Some objects and methods are named in the same way, but almost the API is different. There are though, other projects which compiles java to javascript which has a rigid parallelism between both worlds like [ST-JS](http://st-js.github.io/), and GWT provides an experimental library called [Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html) whose API is almost identical to javascript (it's only available for Chrome).